# Get related taxonomy of Product on Single Product Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display related taxonomy of Product on Single Product WordPress. Added `$product->ID` but it breaks the page. Without it all works but displays all taxonomy and not only related.

```
<?php global $product; 
    $terms=get_terms($product->ID, 'custom_features'); 

    foreach ($terms as $term) { 
        echo '<il><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'custom_features').'">'.$term->name.'</a></il>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?php
$features = get_terms('custom_features');

foreach($features as $feature)
    {
    $feature_link = get_term_link($feature);
    if (is_wp_error($feature_link))
        {
        continue;
        }

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url($feature_link) . '">' . $feature->name . '</a>';
    }
}
```